# Não está persistindo as Preferencias criadas no Android Studio com conexão ao Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, login, sharedpreferences

Começamos a pouco desenvolver um aplicativo. Optamos por conectar com o banco Firebase usando usuário de e-mail e senha. Esta funcionando normalmente o login e a criação de novos usuários, no entanto, minha classe Preferencias não fica salva, e toda vez que encerro o aplicativo, ela pede o usuário e senha novamente.
Como faço para que ela fica salva na "memória" do aplicativo?

Minha classe Login (chamada de MainActivity):

```
package e.servidor.myapplication.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.SharedLibraryInfo;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

import e.servidor.myapplication.DAO.ConfiguracaoFirebase;
import e.servidor.myapplication.Entidades.Usuarios;
import e.servidor.myapplication.Helper.Preferencias;
import e.servidor.myapplication.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button buttonlogin;
    private EditText editTextsenha;
    private EditText editTextemail;
    private TextView textViewcliqueaqui;
    private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
    private Usuarios usuarios;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextemail);
        editTextsenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextsenha);
        textViewcliqueaqui = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcliqueaqui);
        buttonlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);

        buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!editTextemail.getText().toString().equals("") && !editTextsenha.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                    usuarios = new Usuarios();
                    usuarios.setEmail(editTextemail.getText().toString());
                    usuarios.setSenha(editTextsenha.getText().toString());
                    validarLogin();



                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Por favor, preencha os campos de E-mail e Senha.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });

        textViewcliqueaqui.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                abreCadastroUsuario();
            }
        });

    }

    private void validarLogin(){

        autenticacao = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
        autenticacao.signInWithEmailAndPassword(usuarios.getEmail(), usuarios.getSenha()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login efetuado com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    abrirTelaPrincipal();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "E-mail ou Senha incorretos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }finish();

            }
        });

    }

    public void abrirTelaPrincipal(){
        Intent intentAbrirTelaPrincipal = new Intent(MainActivity.this, telaprincipal.class);
        startActivity(intentAbrirTelaPrincipal);
    }

    public void abreCadastroUsuario(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cadastro.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Minha classe Preferencias:

```
package e.servidor.myapplication.Helper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Preferencias {


    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private String NOME_ARQUIVO = "myapplication.preferences";
    private int MODE=0;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private final String CHAVE_IDENTIFICADOR = "IdentificadorUsuarioLogado";
    private final String CHAVE_EMAIL = "EmailUsuarioLogado";

    public  Preferencias(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(NOME_ARQUIVO,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void SalvarUsuarioPreferencias (String IdentificadorUsuario, String IdentificadorEmail) {
        editor.putString(CHAVE_IDENTIFICADOR, IdentificadorUsuario);
        editor.putString(CHAVE_EMAIL, IdentificadorEmail);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getIdentificador(){ 

        return preferences.getString(CHAVE_IDENTIFICADOR,null);
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return preferences.getString(CHAVE_EMAIL, null);
    }
}
```

Minha Classe Usuarios:

```
package e.servidor.myapplication.Entidades;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import e.servidor.myapplication.DAO.ConfiguracaoFirebase;

public class Usuarios {
    private String id;
    private String email;
    private String senha;


    public Usuarios() {
    }

    public void salvar(){
        DatabaseReference referenciaFirebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();
        referenciaFirebase.child("usuario").child(String.valueOf(getId())).setValue(this);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> toMap () {
        HashMap<String, Object> HasMapUsuario = new HashMap<>();

        HasMapUsuario.put("id", getId());
        HasMapUsuario.put("email", getEmail());
        HasMapUsuario.put("senha", getSenha());
        return HasMapUsuario;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não vejo onde chamou a classe Preferencias na sua MainActivity. Parece que você está fazendo o login sempre com os dados do EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o problema é o seguinte, você não está verificando se a instancia do usuário do Firebase está com algum usuário logado.
Quando vc entra na tela de login, não verifica se a um usuário logado, então faz o login novamente e sobrescreve a instancia do usuário.
Coloque esse código na oncreate da sua activity de login

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

try {
    Log.i("Entrou","Entrou no diferente de nulo" + " " + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MenuOrdemServico.class));
}catch (NullPointerException n) {
    // entrou no catch, mAuth == null
}
```

Comment: obrigada. funcionou perfeitamente o comando.